# Invoking annotation 'methods' in Scala

Tags: scala, annotations

In Java I can do following thing:

`String table = Foo.class.getAnnotation(Table.class).name();`

How can I archive this in Scala? Even annotations defined in Java do not seem to have those "name()" methods ...

Comment: With `Foo.class` referring to the class of an object Foo. As @M. A. D. has pointed out, to refer to the class Foo itself you need to use `classOf[Foo]`. I suppose that's the reason you can't get the annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
val table = classOf[Foo].getAnnotation(classOf[Table]).name()
```

That works if you have something like this:

```
@java.lang.annotation.Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@java.lang.annotation.Target({java.lang.annotation.ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
public @interface Table {
    public String name();
}
```

This is the annotation definition that should exist in a Java source file.

And the Foo class:

```
@Table(name="hello")
class Foo {

}
```